# Launch flutter app automatically when FCM received

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to open my flutter app automatically when I received Firebase Cloud Message. I can open it by clicking the notification. But I need to work open it automatically.

Comment: I do not believe that this functionality can every be implemented. This would give a developer the ability to create pop-up ads.

Comment: Okay. Is there any way to launch an app in a mobile automatically?

Comment: I do not believe that there is, sorry.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.